# OAuth for Amazon API GAteway

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, oauth, access-token, aws-api-gateway

I have my Rest API's configured in API Gateway. I want to implement OAuth on top of it so that the access to the url's are authenticated. I know that Lambda functions will be required here. Following are my questions:
1. Any good third party oauth providers that I can link with my project?

2. Scaling needs will be pretty high, possibly around 1M/second. Will these providers be scalable enough?

I would want to be doing everything programmatically. Like mostly these providers will require registration in order to acquire client id's and secrets. I want that also to happen programmatically as the no of users signing up will be dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. i find [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/documents/getting_started) good and also provide a [guide](https://www.authlete.com/documents/apigateway_lambda_oauth) for Amazon API Gateway
2. Yes, they can scale pretty well (check the pricing section) if you are willing to pay enough

Comment: On Feb 11, 2016, Amazon announced a new mechanism named **[Custom Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)** which you can delegate validation of access tokens to. The new guide by Authlete explaining how to achieve Custom Authorizer + OAuth is here: **[Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorizer + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/custom_authorizer)**

Comment: **[Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/)** is scalable, but in addition, it should be noted that Amazon API Gateway can cache results of access token validation for performance. The default value of cache time is 300 seconds (= 5 minutes) and the maximum value is 3600 seconds (= 1 hour). By increasing the cache time, you can reduce access to a custom authorizer. Read the online document for details about cache time: **[Enable Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorization](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)**

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki I have implemented the authorizer code on the link by you only: https://gist.github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/054a8dd54da01fe8fbc4

Now this authorizes the bearer token so I can bind this to my API call. However, just to be quick, could you tell me how do I generate the the access token? I have API key and secret and also its base64

Comment: @AnshulVerma
(1) Access the following URL: `https://api.authlete.com/api/auth/authorization/direct/{service-api-key}?response_type=token&client_id={client-id}`
(2) Input your service API key and service API secret.
(3) Click the "Authorize" button.
/ See **[4. Test](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/custom_authorizer/test)** and **[Getting Started](https://www.authlete.com/documents/getting_started)** for details.